# WOL not working

Tags: windows-7, freebsd, wake-on-lan

I have a Marvell Yukon integrated NIC and i have installed the WOL package on my freeBSD-based NAS. I'm trying to wake my PC using the command "wol M:A:C:A:D:D:R". Command line spits back that it is "waking" however nothing happens.

I found no reference to WOL whatsoever in BIOS and i enabled Magic Packet WOL in windows on that interface. Also double-checked MAC addr and that i entered it in the correct format in "wol". I'm on Windows 7.

What next? =/

Comment: Just ensuring the obvious (and guessing the command would have failed otherwise): `M:A:C:A:D:D:R` does read the actual MAC, right?

Comment: Course it does :)

Answer (score 1):

So I've had a couple issues with this. Here are some steps to get it working.

1. Make sure your bios setting allow WOL. Some motherboard have more than one setting that you need to change. your best bet is to google MOTHERBOADMANUFACTURE MOTHERBOARDMODEL wol bios settings
2. Make sure your turn off Fast boot in power setting. Go to Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\System Settings. You may have to go to power options and click the "Choose what the power buttons do" on the left. Click the Change setting that are currently unavailable and make sure "turn of fast startup (recommended)" is unchecked.
   [Pic of System settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPvVS.png)

3)Make sure your adaptor setting are correct. Go to device manager right click the adaptor your using under Network adapters and click properties. Go to the Power management tab and uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".
[Adaptor properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH5bZ.png)

one issue I had was that even though I unchecked that I still how to go to Advance tab for the adapter properties in device management and set the following options:

Energy Efficient Ethernet -> Disabled
Energy Saving mode -> Disabled
Wake on Magic Packet -> Enabled
Wake on pattern match -> Enabled
EEE Mode -> Enabled

Answer (score 0):

Check under the power management settings in your BIOS. It may not explicitly say WOL. Also verify that your NAS and PC are on the same broadcast domain. You could also test by connecting the NAS directly to the PC with a cross-over cable.

Comment: Where does the broadcast domain end? I have my network connected like this:
NAS -> ISP modem with built in switch -> another switch -> PC to WOL.

Comment: That __should__ work. Try with the two devices connected to the same switch.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I have an asus p5k with windows 7 and wol working on perfection from one moment to another wol stop working.
I tested again and reinstalled Windows 7 and nothing. I tried with xp and worked without problems.
I dont undestando why stop working with windows7 and with the XP is ok.